# Javascript object not recognized as DOM object for addEventListener

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

I'm trying to wrap my head around why this code isn't working. I read up on the DOM and adding event listeners, and I understand that an event listener can only be added to an object of the DOM. Technically the returned value of the _get_elem should be a DOM object and yet it still doesn't work. If anyone has any idea of why this doesn't work or point me in the direction of a resource that can explain how to do it, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
window.onload = funtion()
{
    // works
    document.getElementByID('element_id').addEventListener('click', _fn(), false); 

    var exfnvar = new exfn();
    // doesn't work
    exfnvar.exel.addEventListener('click', _fn(), false);
    // also doesn't work 
    exfnvar._get_elem().addEventListener('click', _fn(), false);
};

var exfn = function()
{
    this.exel = document.getElementByID('element_id');
    this._get_elem = function()
    {
        return document.getElementByID('element_id');
    }
};

function _fn()
{
    // do something.
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling the function and giving the return value as the callback to the event listener.  instead you have to give the function as the callback.

change

`document.getElementByID('element_id').addEventListener('click', _fn(), false);`

to

```
document.getElementByID('element_id').addEventListener('click', _fn, false);
```

Same with other listners..

Comment: This.
The browser will call your function as needed, that's the point of an event handler. You only need to pass in the reference. You were passing in the return value of your handler, which I suspect is undefined, because there isn't much reason to put a return statement in an event handler.

Comment: I cannot believe such a small oversight caused everything to fail. Strangely enough I didn't have () before and it still didn't work, must have been something else then. Thank you for pointing out my error!

Answer (score 1):

If you write `.addEventListener('click', _fn(), fale)` the `_fn` is being executed in this very line and the result (return value) is being added as the event callback.

You have omitted the function body of `_fn`, but assuming it doesn't return another function you should have used `.addEventListener('click', _fn, false)` - this way a reference to `_fn` is added as a listener, not the result of its execution.

Comment: Thank you for your help! @plbsam beat you by 2 minutes though, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine for me after a few changes.  One thing to note is capitalization:

```
getElementById
```

vs

```
getElementByID
```

Also, when you're passing a function as a callback, you don't want to include the parentheses.  You only want to include that when you are executing the function.